# Error when calling function inside the function

Tags: php, function

I'm making a class that has several functions. There is one thing that makes me confused, which is when I call the function itself in its function:

in the following function, I don't get an error when I call the getChildKey function inside the function itself:

```
    function getChildKey1($FPTree)
{
  function getChildKey($FPTree){
    $result = [];
    if (isset($FPTree['child'])){
      foreach ($FPTree['child'] as $key => $value){
        $result[$key]=getChildKey($value);
      }
    }
    if (empty($result)){
      return 'gak ada array';
    }
    return $result;
  }
  $output = [];
  foreach ($FPTree as $index => $child){
    $output[$index]=getChildKey($child);
  }
return $output;
}
```

and I get an error when I try to create a function similar to the `getChildKey` function, which calls the function itself in it:

```
function pathFinder($arr = [], $needle)
{

    $path = '';
    $paths = [];

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

        if (is_array($value)) {
            $path .= $key . "->";
            pathFinder($value, $needle); //error here


        } else {
            if ($key === $needle) {
                $paths[] = $path . $key; 

            }
        }
    }
    return $paths; // return all found paths to key $needle
}
```

Why did it happen? what do I have to do so that the `pathFinder` function can call itself in it?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: `$this->pathFinder()`

Comment: `getChildKey` is a function insides method, `pathFinder` is a method, so it needs to be called by an instance

Comment: @Viney I got note from vscode undifined function 'pathFinder'

Comment: @ArunAS and one that makes me confused is why when I make this pathfinder function in a separate file it runs normally without errors?

Answer (score 0):

When you define a function, and call it that time (if function was found) php creates a scope which will be like a different "house" for all variables and functions that are declared/defined inside it. That's the reason we sometimes need to use the keyword `global` when we want to reference `$var1` which is defined outside the function (and class if any) and we happen to have a variable with the same name declared in our function

CASE 1:

```
function A($args1)   
{ 
   //---- scope of A starts here
   function B($args2)
   { return 'hello from B'; }

    B();   // call B

   //---- scope of A ends here
}
```

CASE 2:

```
function A($args1)   
{ 
   //---- scope of A starts here

    A();   // call A
    //but where is A?

   //---- scope of A ends here
}
```

In 1st case the A function's block (anything between { })  is self-contained block meaning it has everything that any code inside it would need in order to run. So when `B()` is encountered php looks within the scope of `A`, whether any function named `B` is defined? Yes!

In 2nd case PHP does the same when it encounters `A()` but on not finding it there, it looks in the global scope ie. all code that is outside of your class to find a function named `A`. Since there isn't any it throws a not found exception

When you use `$this->A()` php knows where to look for this function ie.inside the same object where it was called from and it run perfectly